# How to accelerate slow matrix multiplication in SymPy?

Tags: performance, matrix, multiplication, sympy

I was writing a tool to solve specific recurrence equations with SymPy, and found that one of the steps that involved a matrix multiplication was taking an extraordinarily long time. For instance, if I try the following in the iPython console,

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: A = Matrix(500, 500, lambda i,j: 2 + abs(i-j) if i-j in [-1, 0, 1] else 0)

In [3]: A[0:7, 0:7]
Out[3]: 
Matrix([
[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2]])

In [4]: A * A
...
```

I've never waited long enough for it to finish.

I appreciate that symbolic manipulation considerably slower than numerical evaluation, but this seems pretty ridiculous. Using Octave or other linear algebra packages can perform this calculation in a fraction of a second.

Does anyone have experience using SymPy's matrix class for rows & columns ~ 1000, with Rational entries?

Comment: are you sure you need **remain "fully-symbolic"** once you have constructed the Matrix? How about moving `A`-values into `numpy.array`? Having mentioned **`Octave`**, it is not possible to compare it directly to the `sympy` symbolic-solver engine. Benchmark your code in `Octave` `tic(); ... ;toc()`-segment and then give `numpy` a try. As tested on A[500,500] of floats, the A*A **took about 19 [msec] in python ( numpy )**

Comment: n.b. Sure, might be I have missed a main point of using the "fully-symbolic" sympy. You wrote about recurrence equations' solver. If it were used for generating a tridiagonal matrix ( as posted in the demo-code ) that would be for sure a great mis-understanding of the adequate use of such powerfull "fully-symbolic" solver tool.

Comment: I was interested in SymPy because it handles rational arithmetic exactly, expanding denominators as needed to not lose precision. In my field of study, it's imperative that the solutions are not truncated via floating point approximation. Their examples in the Matrix class encapsulate this Rational arithmetic. Is there a way to use numpy with SymPy's Rational class?

Comment: Truthfully, by the time the solver reaches the stage of matrix multiplication, I've already evaluated out all the symbols in the matrix for numerical values, so I'm just interested in linear algebra with arbitrary-precision rational arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks mack for the notes. There are pythonic classes for such purpose. Ref. below for more details.

Comment: SymPy also takes some time to print this matrix, so be sure to time `a = A * A`, not `A*A`, as the latter will also try to print the matrix.

Comment: I opened an issue about this in the SymPy issue tracker. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Arbitrary-precision as a must, speed as a nice-to-have

There are a few pythonic classes for such purpose, that may interest your arbitrary precision calculi

- **`decimal.Decimal()`**
- **`fractions.Fraction( numerator = 0, denominator = 1 )`**

These are indispensable for precise calculations, be it for large-scale astronomy, DEP-simulations or other fields, where precision must not degrade alongside the computation strategy progress over long scales of time / events / recursion and similar threats to standard number-representations.

Personally I worked with `decimal.Decimal()` ( for up to 5.000.000 digits precision in crypto-sequence randomness analyses ) but was not focused on having 'em "inside" **`numpy`** matrix.

Numpy can bear these types in it's matrix-dataStructures ( `dtype = decimal.Decimal` syntax et al), however testing is needed, to verify it's vectorised functions operations and the overall speed once handling these lovely pythonic classes' instances.

### Performance

As an initial observation on numpy speed on a standard ("*dense*" sounds funny for this scale ) 2x2 `decimal.Decimal`-s:

```
>>> aClk.start();m*m;aClk.stop()
array([[Decimal('0.01524157875323883675019051999'),
        Decimal('5.502209507697009702374335655')],
       [Decimal('1.524157875323883675019051999'),
        Decimal('11.94939027587381419881628113')]], dtype=object)
5732L # 5.7 msec_______________________________________________________________
```

While the same on `dtype = numpy.float96` took

```
>>> aClk.start();f*f;aClk.stop()
array([[ 0.042788046,  0.74206772],
       [ 0.10081096,  0.46544855]], dtype=float96)
2979L # 2.9 msec_______________________________________________________________
```

For a 500 x 500 fully-populated **`dtype = fractions.Fraction`**

```
>>> aClk.start();M*M;aClk.stop()
array([[Fraction(9, 64), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(64, 25), ...,
        Fraction(64, 81), Fraction(16, 81), Fraction(36, 1)],
        ..,
       [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(9, 4), Fraction(4, 1), ...,
        Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(25, 36), Fraction(1, 1)]], dtype=object)
2692088L # 2.7 sec_<<<_Fraction_______________________________vs. 19 msec float96
```

For a 500 x 500 fully-populated dense **`dtype = decimal.Decimal`**

```
>>> aClk.start();D*D;aClk.stop()
array([[Decimal('0.140625'), Decimal('0.25'), Decimal('2.56'), ...,
        Decimal('0.7901234567901234567901234568'),
        Decimal('0.1975308641975308641975308642'), Decimal('36')],
       [Decimal('3.24'), Decimal('0.25'), Decimal('0.25'), ...,
        Decimal('0.02040816326530612244897959185'), Decimal('0.04'),
        Decimal('0.1111111111111111111111111111')],
       [Decimal('0.1111111111111111111111111111'), Decimal('0.25'),
        Decimal('2.25'), ..., Decimal('0.5102040816326530612244897959'),
        Decimal('0.25'), Decimal('0.0625')],
       ...,
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('5.444444444444444444444444443'),
        Decimal('16'), ..., Decimal('25'), Decimal('0.81'), Decimal('0.04')],
       [Decimal('1'), Decimal('7.111111111111111111111111113'),
        Decimal('1'), ..., Decimal('0'), Decimal('81'), Decimal('2.25')],
       [Decimal('1'), Decimal('2.25'), Decimal('4'), ..., Decimal('0.25'),
        Decimal('0.6944444444444444444444444444'), Decimal('1')]], dtype=object)
4789338L # 4.8 sec_<<<_Decimal_______________________________vs. 19 msec float96
2692088L # 2.7 sec_<<<_Fraction______________________________vs. 19 msec float96
```

### May expectations for a Tri-diagonal matrix 1000x1000 go under 50 msec?

as there are 3,000 non-zero ( sparse-representation ) elements, as opposed to 250,000 cells in fully-populated 500x500 matrices tested above, there is a huge performance jump for using these pythonic classes for your arbitrary precision computations. Fraction has a more space once the engine may use an advantage of `numerator`/`denominator` construction for MUL / DIV operations over Decimal, however exact performance envelopes shall be tested in-vivo, on real cases your computing approach is using.

### Sympy syntax for `SparseMatrix` & tests on 1000x1000 Tri-Diagonals

a real test on 1000x1000 `SparseMatrix`, as proposed by @tmyklebu, took a bit longer to get elaborated due to installaton troubles, however **may give you some further insight into real-world implementation Projects:**

```
>>> F = sympy.SparseMatrix( 1000, 1000, { (0,0): 1} )        # .Fraction()
>>> D = sympy.SparseMatrix( 1000, 1000, { (0,0): 1} )        # .Decimal()

>>> for i in range( 1000 ):                                  # GEN to have F & D hold
...     for j in range( 1000 ):                              #     SAME values,
...         if i-j in [-1,0,1]:                              # but DIFF representations
...            num = int( 100 * numpy.random.random() )      #     
...            den = int( 100 * numpy.random.random() ) + 1  # + 1 to avoid DIV!0
...            F[i,j] = fractions.Fraction( numerator = num, denominator = den )
...            D[i,j] = decimal.Decimal( str( num ) ) / decimal.Decimal( str( den ) )

# called in Zig-Zag(F*F/D*D/F*F/D*D/...) order to avoid memory-access cache artifacts

>>> aClk.start();VOID=F*F;aClk.stop()
770353L                                      # notice the 1st eval took  TRIPLE LONGER
205585L                                      # notice the 2nd+
205364L # 0.205 sec_<<<_Fraction()____________________________vs. 0.331 sec Decimal()


>>> aClk.start();VOID=D*D;aClk.stop()
383137L # 0.383 sec_<<<_Decimal()____________________________vs. 0.770 sec 1st Fraction()
390164L # 0.390 sec_<<<_Decimal()____________________________vs. 0.205 sec 2nd Fraction()
331291L # 0.331 sec_<<<_Decimal()____________________________vs. 0.205 sec 3rd Fraction()

>>> F[0:4,0:4]
Matrix([
[ 1/52,  6/23,     0,     0],
[42/29, 29/12,     1,     0],
[    0, 57/88, 39/62, 13/57],
[    0,     0, 34/83, 26/95]])
>>> D[0:4,0:4]
Matrix([
[0.0192307692307692, 0.260869565217391,                 0,                 0],
[  1.44827586206897,  2.41666666666667,               1.0,                 0],
[                 0, 0.647727272727273, 0.629032258064516, 0.228070175438596],
[                 0,                 0, 0.409638554216867, 0.273684210526316]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look into numpy and Fraction. Those performance examples are kind of meaningless though, since even the SymPy version performs quickly on such a tiny scale. I'm going to leave the question open, in case someone knows a way to make SymPy's Matrix/Rational classes perform faster.

Comment: Sure, mack. In case numpy remains to maintain a constant "double" overhead on Decimal/Fraction computation-operations as compared to float96, it is still quite fast. After a few tests, I will post you **some observations on Decimal and Fraction classes inside numpy**

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [sympy's sparse matrices](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/sparse.html) instead of dense matrices?  The matrices that arise when solving (linear) recurrences are typically sparse; one technique gives you a matrix with 1's on the first superdiagonal and zeroes everywhere else except the bottom row, where the recurrence coefficients go.

Comment: I tried a similar example with SymPy's sparse implementation, and it still takes several seconds to do. While it's a step in the right direction, I'm still interested if there's an efficient way to get the dense matrix class to work quickly for numeric entries.

Comment: @mack: I kinda doubt it, at least for the sizes you're looking at.  A 500x500 * 500x500 dense matrix multiplication is going to take 125M *really* complicated operations---the arithmetic that goes on will be vastly outweighed by per-multiplication overhead.

Comment: My comment is motivated by my limited experience with Sage. It's an alternative to SymPy that also has a matrix class that does arbitrary precision rational arithmetic. Unlike SymPy, Sage can do this little 500x500 multiplication almost instantly in comparison(~0.5s), but I just can't stand Sage's weird API.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `sympy` for matrix operations, but I can repro the slowness you are experiencing with this code. It seems that the matrix operations in sympy are not that great.

I will recommend you to use `numpy`, which has great matrix operations and is very fast. Here is a copy of your code in numpy, which does the multiplication in under 1 sec on my laptop:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.matrix([[2 + abs(i-j) if i-j in [-1, 0, 1] else 0 for i in range(0, 500)] for j in range(0, 500)])

In [3]: A[0:7,0:7]
Out[3]:
matrix([[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2]])

In [4]: A * A
Out[4]:
matrix([[13, 12,  9, ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [12, 22, 12, ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 9, 12, 22, ...,  0,  0,  0],
        ...,
        [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 22, 12,  9],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 12, 22, 12],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  9, 12, 13]])
```