# Unlimited-precision decimal math support in Python itself

Tags: python, math

I have a question towards the pure math support of Python. As far as I know, at some point the calculation is not precise enough in Python, given that the operands are large enough.

Is there some kind of unlimited precision support in Python the language itself, rather than importing a library like [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)? I'm asking for something like `BigDecimal` in Java, which supports unlimited precision of decimal calculation.

Comment: How about [`bigfloat`](http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/)?

Comment: Have you looked at the decimal module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Thank you both! I think the decimal module @tom suggested is the one I want. Please convert it to an answer?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I understand that unlimited integer precision is supported by Python, which is a very cool feature. However what I want is a kind of calculation that does not lose precision in the process, for example if I take square root of `3999999995999999997` I get `1999999999.0`, and if take the square of the result I get `3999999996000000001L`.

Comment: @AlbusShin I've converted it.

Comment: If the decimal module is the answer to your question, then you should not ask for unlimited precision but for arbitrary precision. The decimal module gives you arbitrary precision but not unlimited precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the decimal module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1):

For python native **`decimal.Decimal`** & **`fractions.Fraction`** performance once harnessed inside `numpy` dense-matrix ( sparse-matrix est'd ) computations -- **quantitative performance comparison** -- kindly ref. >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26248202/3666197